# How can I set the interval unit between labels on the x-axis to a value higher than 255 in Microsoft Excel 2013?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2013

In Microsoft Excel 2007 I could set the interval unit between labels on the x-axis to a value higher than 255:

[image]

In Microsoft Excel 2013 whenever I set a value higher than 255, my value get reset to 255:

[image]

Is there any way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find any documentation about this limit, but I see the same thing. A workaround could be to add another data series for labelling purposes and use the XY Chart Labeller tool to replace the axis labels with series labels that look like axis labels.

Comment: Thanks, creating a data series for labelling purposes is indeed what I ended up doing. Weird limit! I don't see it in [Excel 2013 specifications and limits](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HA103980614.aspx) (or maybe they used some weird feature name to designate it).

Answer (score -1):

If you have a machine with Office 2010 on it you can edit the Excel chart to have a larger x label sample spacing than the Office 2013/365 limit of 255. The office 2010 saved file when opened with Office 2013/365 will display the charts with the larger label interval fine. It is just Office 2013/365's user interface that is broken.

Bottom line is stay with Office 2010 as long as possible, the latest Office suites have no really useful new features and an even worse user interface. Although Office 2003 has the best user interface, in today's world nearly everybody is using the XML format files so compatibility issues makes using Office 2013 impractical.

As for alternative non Microsoft Office suites, I find the free Open Office/Libre Office suites user interface are still not as good as MS to work in, though if Microsoft continues to degrade theirs, that statement may change.

The latest MS office suites have difficulty importing many early MS office suite files, but surprisingly Open Office/Libre Office can generally import and then export XML versions of these files fine - so having one of the free suites on your machine is useful.

Shame we need to have so many office suites to do what used to be available on a single platform.